# how to call a Rest Module of Zend framework from another module using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, rest, zend-framework

I have a tournament module which is REST.

I can call it using http://localhost:8888/tournament. Now what I wants to do is,
I am having another module that uses this API.

The another module is tournament module,on load I am fetching the API with the help of curl thats working fine but I have ADD button on my Page and I wants to use ajax to call API for adding data on clicking on add button.

how should I do it ?

I have created REST in Zend with dynamodb as backend.

Comment: @stephen It could be great if you have given answer instead of what you did. :)

Comment: @Stephan: your changes introduced other grammatical mistakes. How is that an improvement?

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Add some code to your post. Rephrase your post too. It's difficult for the reader to identify the specific problem you're facing.

Comment: @M.M Correct what you think are grammatical mistakes.

Comment: @stephan  If I don't know what I have to do ,how can I write code for that ?...and that I have asked to the user.

Comment: @BhavikJoshi Do you have 2 apps - one being the REST API and the other being a website - interacting with each other? Do I understand correctly that you are calling your API from the other app with a get request and now you are trying to implement a post request? What kind of requests does your REST controller implement?

Comment: yes,You have understand right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can call ajax onCLick of button and call AJAX like..

```
$('#btnadad').on('click',function (e){       
   alert("ok");
   $.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   url :"/tournament",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
        console.log('success',data);

   },
   error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
}); 
 e.preventDefault();
});
```